# Add JavaScript logic in dynamically loaded template AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm dynamically loading templates which is working fine. Now my concern is I need to add a JavaScript logic to template

I need to use something like this in my template.

```
{{ var entries = 0; }}
{{ for(var r = 0; r < d; r++) }}
```

Suppose my template returns this HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names" ><span>{{x.name}}</span>{{some logic here which is plain js. var a=[] if(a=b){}}}</div>
```

My question is how to achieve this.

Comment: so what is the problem.

Comment: i need too add this code in my json. i know ng-reapeat will repeat all the data in it

Comment: What do you mean "need to add this code in JSON".

Comment: @Ved my bad i have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries track by $index">
    {{entry}},{{$index}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-repeat`.

```
  <div ng-repeat="entry in entries">
    {{entry}}
  </div>
```

If you need the index:

```
  <div ng-repeat="entry in entries">
    {{entry}},{{$index}}
  </div>
```

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-init="entries[0,1,2,3,4]">//Use ng-int to initialize data

<div ng-repeat="data in entries">// use ng-repeat to loop over
    {{data}}
  </div>

</div>
```